# Enable admin panel for non-admin user

Tags: typo3, typoscript

There are some menu entries added to the admin panel. These link to some php files which are opened in the frame so that it is integrated into Typo 3. Everything is working fine for the admin users. Now I created a non admin user which should also have access to this tools. The user has the access right to these tools, but they don't show up when logged in as non-admin user. I think that the admin panel is only available for admin users.

So how can I grant access to the admin panel only for the desired tools? I thought typoscript like this

```
admPanel {
  enable.edit = 1
  hide = 0
}
```

can do it. But it doesn't. I've added this code in the options tab of the user.

### Solution

Taken from the blog post [TYPO3 Adminwerkzeuge für Backend Benutzer anzeigen](http://www.quirks-modus.de/archives/28):

1. Open `/typo3/mod/tools/conf.php` and change from **`admin`** to **`user,group`**

   ```
   #$MCONF['access']='admin';
   $MCONF['access']='user,group';
   ```

   Save file and upload to server. This was the step for enabling the admin tools under access rights (see step 2)).
2. Go to admin-tools -> user, edit user, go to access rights, add admin panel.
3. Open `/typo3/sysext/belog/mod/conf.php` and do the same as in 1.:

   ```
   #$MCONF['access']='admin';
   $MCONF['access']='user,group';
   ```

With this code you can enable the sub entries of the admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set

```
 admPanel {
  enable.all = 1
  hide = 0
 }
```

You can activate each modul at its own

```
  admPanel.enable {
    preview = 0/1
    cache= 0/1
    publish= 0/1
    edit= 0/1
    tsdebug= 0/1
    info= 0/1
  }
```

More option you will find at: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsconfig/4.6.0/view/1/4/#id2313502

Comment: My own "extension" (only php files) where integrated into the admin panel. But the user doesn't saw the admin panel. So my "extensions" cannot be set through preview, cache ... Only the admin panel in general should be available (my extensions can be already be activated in the access list), because it and everything within it was hidden. Can your TS do that?

Comment: admPanel.enable.all = 1 set in user TS Config (where you did) should work.
You need to activate the admPanel via Page TS Config itself "config.admPanel = 1" but i guess, it is allready done, because as admin you can see the panel.